# Incluindo string a partir de uma posição

Tags: javascript

Estou quebrando a cabeça com um item que talvez seja até simples de fazer mas depois de doze horas de trabalho a mente não ajuda... rsrsrsrs

Amigos, eu tenho uma query stirng, por exemplo:

```
&requiredfields=(Vencedor:vencedor).(Categoria:competitividade|Categoria:produtividade)
```

Onde eu preciso incluir um novo item à ela numa posição em especifico. Vejam só:

```
&requiredfields=(Vencedor:vencedor).(Categoria:jovem parceiro|Categoria:competitividade|Categoria:produtividade)
```

Notem que inclui `Categoria:jovem parceiro` na query string no início dos parenteses e fiz uma separação por `|`. A posição de onde começa esse caracter em especifico eu já tenho, pra contextualizar melhor, quando itens possuem a chave igual, eles devem ficar dentro do mesmo parenteses separado por `|`, desta forma, a posição de onde começa - nesse exemplo - `Categoria` eu já tenho. Preciso seguir adiante.

Poderiam me ajudar nesse problema. Preciso fazer isso com JavaScript.
Desde já agradeço!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você já tem a posição e quer inserir o texto2 dentro do texto1, na posição X, você pode usar:

```
var texto1 = "&requiredfields=(Vencedor:vencedor).(Categoria:competitividade|Categoria:produtividade)"
var texto2 = "Categoria:jovem parceiro|"
var posicao = 37; //Coloque aqui a posição que você já tem
var novotexto = [texto1.slice(0, posicao), texto2, texto1.slice(posicao)].join('');
```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado Icaro.